# Как внести сразу несколько объектов через форму?

Tags: python, django

Есть страница с формой отправки данных документа на django. 
Форма имеет несколько табов(вкладок). Один таб на каждый вид документа.
Для всех видов документа одна модель в базе данных. На каждом табе формы одинаковые поля и передается скрытое поле "вид документа".
Как сделать, чтобы при отправки формы, информация из всех табов вносилась в базу данных.

Answer (score 0):

Более правильным архитектурным решением было бы использовать разные формы для разных моделей. Но если очень нужен именно такой костыль, то можно использовать обычную форму вместо модельной и в представлении вручную создавать модели, перенося в них данные из формы.